# Custom environment breaks listings command

Tags: listings, environments

Following a LaTeX beginners’ tutorial, I am toying around with custom environments and commands. The following is supposed to be the logical markup for (for instance) a student task:

```
\newenvironment{task}{
\newcommand{\subtask}[1]{
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)},resume]\item{##1}\end{enumerate}}
}{}
```

(Note that this is a minimal example. I do realize that defining the environment like this is quite pointless.)

However, this setup breaks a *listings* environment if it is passed as a subtask, as the following MWE shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
\newenvironment{task}{
    \newcommand{\subtask}[1]{
        \begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)},resume]\item{##1}\end{enumerate}}
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{task}
\subtask{\{0, 1\}, with unescaped braces, becomes \lstinline!{0, 1}!.}
\subtask{\{0, 1\}, with escaped braces, becomes  \lstinline!\{0, 1\}!.}
\subtask{\{0\}, with unescaped braces, becomes \lstinline!{0}!.}
\subtask{\{0\}, with escaped braces, becomes \lstinline!\{0\}!.}
\end{task}

Typing the environment commands by hand:
\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}, resume]\item{\{0, 1\}, with unescaped braces, becomes \lstinline!{0, 1}!.}\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}, resume]\item{\{0, 1\}, with escaped braces, becomes  \lstinline!\{0, 1\}!.}\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}, resume]\item{\{0\}, with unescaped braces, becomes \lstinline!{0}!.}\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}, resume]\item{\{0\}, with escaped braces, becomes \lstinline!\{0\}!.}\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: The mwe’s output]

Note the moving around of the “1“, the comma and a space in the first a). This does not happen if I escape the braces inside the listing (which is usually unnecessary, as exemplified by the text between the lists) or if I type the environment’s exact commands by hand, as shown in the second list.

My questions after lots of text are now:

- Why is it necessary to escape the braces inside the environment?
- How come the listing’s contents are moved around and doubled if I don’t do that?
- How can I fix this?